# Javascript soft scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, click, dom-events

I'm developing a script to scroll pages  like in smartphones (touching the screen). I have done in jQuery and jscrollto [script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/155708), but I want to do it in pure Javascript. Here is my code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        touchNavigation
// @namespace   here
// @include     http://*

// @version     0.1
// @grant       none

// ==/UserScript==

document.body.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown);
document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp)
var y0=0;
var y1=0;
var diferencia=0;

function mouseDown(event)
{
  y0=event.clientY;
}

function mouseUp(event)
{
    var i;
    y1=event.clientY;
    diferencia=y1-y0;


    if(diferencia>0){
        i=-10;
        while(diferencia>0){
            setTimeout(desplazamiento, 250, i);
            diferencia+=i;
        }
    }else{
        i=10;
        while(diferencia<0){
            setTimeout(desplazamiento, 250, i);
            diferencia+=i;
        }
    }

}

function desplazamiento(diferencia){


    window.scrollBy(0,diferencia);

}
```

The script works. But the displacement is in one step. It should be more softly.

What could be the trouble of this section?

```
 if(diferencia>0){
            i=-10;
            while(diferencia>0){
                setTimeout(desplazamiento, 250, i);
                diferencia+=i;
            }
        }else{
            i=10;
            while(diferencia<0){
                setTimeout(desplazamiento, 250, i);
                diferencia+=i;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You animation function seems to be linear. For smooth scrolling you'd need some sort of curved function (e.g. starts fast, then slows down). Also, consider `requestAnimationFrame`, as it should give you smoother animation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ivan from userscript submited the code to make the scroll in javascript softly. You can see here.

http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/155832

I don't know how work but work perfectly.